# Task.Run and UI Progress Updates

Tags: c#, asynchronous, progress

This code snippet is from [Stephen Cleary's blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/09/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-round-5.html) and gives an example of how to report progress when using Task.Run. I would like to know why there are no cross thread issues with updating the UI, by which I mean why is invoke not required?

```
private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var progressHandler = new Progress<string>(value =>
    {
        label2.Text = value;
    });
    var progress = progressHandler as IProgress<string>;
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i != 100; ++i)
        {
            if (progress != null)
                progress.Report("Stage " + i);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    });
    label2.Text = "Completed.";
}
```

Comment: @newbieguy string concatenations calls the ToString() method automatically

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`Progress<T>` catches the current `SynchronisationContext` when it is instantiated. Whenever you call `Report`, it secretly delegates that to the captured context. In the example, the captured context is the UI, meaning that no exceptions occur.

Comment: Do you know what thread priority is given to this? ie: Normal, Background, ApplicationIdle etc..

Comment: @Kelly the dispatcher priority is Normal. See the remarks section here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchersynchronizationcontext.post(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 14):

The `Progress<T>` constructor captures the current `SynchronizationContext` object.

The `SynchronizationContext` class is a facility that abstracts the particulars of the involved threading model. That is, in Windows Forms it will use `Control.Invoke`, in WPF it will use `Dispatcher.Invoke`, etc.

When the `progress.Report` object is called, the `Progress` object itself knows that it should run its delegate using the captured `SynchronizationContext`.

In other terms, it works because `Progress` has been designed to handle that without the developer having to explicitly say it.

Answer (score 8):

It seems you're confused due the fact that part of this cross-thread machinery is hidden from developer eyes so you just have to "take and use": https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis

> We introduced the IProgress interface to enable you to create an
> experience for displaying progress. This interface exposes a Report(T)
> method, which the async task calls to report progress. You expose this
> interface in the signature of the async method, and the caller must
> provide an object that implements this interface. Together, the task
> and the caller create a very useful linkage (and could be running on
> different threads).
>
> We also provided the Progress class, which is an implementation of
> IProgress. You are encouraged to use Progress in your
> implementation, because it handles all the bookkeeping around saving
> and restoring the synchronization context. Progress exposes both an
> event and an Action callback, which are called when the task
> reports progress. This pattern enables you to write code that simply
> reacts to progress changes as they occur. Together, IProgress and
> Progress provide an easy way to pass progress information from a
> background task to the UI thread.

Just one more thing to mention: progress notification will be invoked **after** the part of the job is done, **not just at that moment**. So, if your UI thread is idling and you have spare CPU core the delay will be almost zero. If your UI thread is busy, the notification will not be invoked until the moment the UI thread is back to idle (regardless how much spare CPU cores your computer has).

Comment: `> If your UI thread is busy, the notification will not be invoked until the moment the UI thread is back to idle`   
- Thank you for that line, I was trying to run `ProgressObj.Report()` from the UI thread, which probably didn't work because the UI thread was already busy and wouldn't execute the `Report()` until it became free.