# Aysnc method still blocking the ui interface

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await

I have this method which is using ODBC and executes the reader async but the method is still blocking my UI for some reason it's loading 4000 records but I am wondering if someone can look at my code see where I am going wrong.

```
async Task<BindingList<PurchaseLinkHeaderC>> GetPurchaseOrders( IProgress<int> progress)
{
    BindingList<PurchaseLinkHeaderC> _purhcaseOrderList = new BindingList<PurchaseLinkHeaderC>();
    try
    {
        string sageDsn = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SageDSN"];
        string sageUsername = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SageUsername"];
        string sagePassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SagePassword"];
        //using (var connection = new OdbcConnection("DSN=SageLine50v24;Uid=Manager;Pwd=;"))

        using (var connection =
            new OdbcConnection(String.Format("DSN={0};Uid={1};Pwd={2};", sageDsn, sageUsername, sagePassword)))
        {
            connection.Open();
            string fromD = dtpFrom.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            string toD = dtpTo.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

            string SQL =
                "SELECT 'ORDER_NUMBER', 'ORDER_OR_QUOTE', 'ORDER_DATE', 'DELIVERY_DATE', 'ORDER_STATUS_CODE', 'ORDER_STATUS', 'DELIVERY_STATUS_CODE', 'DELIVERY_STATUS', 'ACCOUNT_REF', 'NAME', 'ADDRESS_1', 'ADDRESS_2', 'ADDRESS_3', 'ADDRESS_4', 'ADDRESS_5', 'C_ADDRESS_1', 'C_ADDRESS_2', 'C_ADDRESS_3', 'C_ADDRESS_4', 'C_ADDRESS_5', 'DEL_NAME', 'DEL_ADDRESS_1', 'DEL_ADDRESS_2', 'DEL_ADDRESS_3', 'DEL_ADDRESS_4', 'DEL_ADDRESS_5', 'VAT_REG_NUMBER', 'REFERENCE', 'CONTACT_NAME', 'TAKEN_BY', 'SUPP_ORDER_NUMBER', 'SUPP_TEL_NUMBER', 'NOTES_1', 'NOTES_2', 'NOTES_3', 'SUPP_DISC_RATE', 'FOREIGN_ITEMS_NET', 'FOREIGN_ITEMS_TAX', 'FOREIGN_ITEMS_GROSS', 'ITEMS_NET', 'ITEMS_TAX', 'ITEMS_GROSS', 'TAX_RATE_1', 'TAX_RATE_2', 'TAX_RATE_3', 'TAX_RATE_4', 'TAX_RATE_5', 'NET_AMOUNT_1', 'NET_AMOUNT_2', 'NET_AMOUNT_3', 'NET_AMOUNT_4', 'NET_AMOUNT_5', 'TAX_AMOUNT_1', 'TAX_AMOUNT_2', 'TAX_AMOUNT_3', 'TAX_AMOUNT_4', 'TAX_AMOUNT_5', 'COURIER_NUMBER', 'COURIER_NAME', 'CONSIGNMENT', 'CARR_NOM_CODE', 'CARR_TAX_CODE', 'CARR_DEPT_NUMBER', 'CARR_DEPT_NAME', 'FOREIGN_CARR_NET', 'FOREIGN_CARR_TAX', 'FOREIGN_CARR_GROSS', 'CARR_NET', 'CARR_TAX', 'CARR_GROSS', 'FOREIGN_INVOICE_NET', 'FOREIGN_INVOICE_TAX', 'FOREIGN_INVOICE_GROSS', 'INVOICE_NET', 'INVOICE_TAX', 'INVOICE_GROSS', 'CURRENCY', 'CURRENCY_TYPE', 'EURO_GROSS', 'EURO_RATE', 'FOREIGN_RATE', 'SETTLEMENT_DUE_DAYS', 'SETTLEMENT_DISC_RATE', 'FOREIGN_SETTLEMENT_DISC_AMOUNT', 'FOREIGN_SETTLEMENT_TOTAL', 'SETTLEMENT_DISC_AMOUNT', 'SETTLEMENT_TOTAL', 'PAYMENT_REF', 'PRINTED', 'PRINTED_CODE', 'POSTED', 'POSTED_CODE', 'QUOTE_STATUS_ID', 'RECURRING_REF', 'DUNS_NUMBER', 'PAYMENT_TYPE', 'BANK_REF', 'GDN_NUMBER', 'PROJECT_ID', 'ANALYSIS_1', 'ANALYSIS_2', 'ANALYSIS_3', 'INVOICE_PAYMENT_ID', 'RESUBMIT_INVOICE_PAYMENT_REQUIRED', 'RECORD_CREATE_DATE', 'RECORD_MODIFY_DATE', 'RECORD_DELETED' FROM 'PURCHASE_ORDER' WHERE ORDER_DATE >='{0}' and ORDER_DATE <='{1}'";

            int counter = 0;
            using (var command = new OdbcCommand(string.Format(SQL, fromD, toD), connection))
            {
                using (var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                {
                    while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                    {
                        var purhcaseOrders = new PurchaseLinkHeaderC();
                        if ((reader["ORDER_NUMBER"] != ""))
                        {
                            counter++;

                            string orderNumber = Convert.ToString(reader["ORDER_NUMBER"]);
                            purhcaseOrders.Order_Number = OrderNumber.ToString();
                            purhcaseOrders.PurchaseOrderNo = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ORDER_NUMBER"]);
                            purhcaseOrders.Name = reader["NAME"].ToString();
                            purhcaseOrders.Selected_PurchaseOrder = false;
                            _purhcaseOrderList.Add(purhcaseOrders);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        logger.Info(ex, "Error at GetSalesOrders " + ex.ToString());
    }

    return _purhcaseOrderList;
}
```

I want to be able to show a progress bar of the list being loaded so I was attempting to call it as this way. But I am not sure how to attach the progress method either.

```
var progressIndicator = new Progress<int>(ReportProgress);
//call async method
BindingList<PurchaseLinkHeaderC> purchaseOrders = await GetPurchaseOrders(progressIndicator);
_masterPurchaseOrders = purchaseOrders;
```

I am hoping that someone can help here.

Comment: What are you doing in `GetPurchaseOrders()` method actually?

Comment: @Rahul the GetPurchaseOrders is shown in its enterity above its going to odbc in sage to retrieve orders from the tables using odbc sql

Comment: You are not [reporting any progress](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28430872/11683) through your `IProgress<int>`. You should also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/11683 for why you must not use `string.Format` to build a query.

Comment: @GSerg that is the secondary issue main issue is the blocking of the ui

Answer (score 2):

When you `await`, the *default* behaviour is to use the sync-context, if one, when coming back from the `async` operation. In the case of a UI application, the sync-context is: the UI.

So; right now, there are a lot of things that *come back* to the UI. This is useful when context matters, but in your case: it doesn't - since you are simply *returning* a list.

This means that you should be able to add `.ConfigureAwait(false)` to a lot of those `await` expressions - for example:

```
while (await reader.ReadAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
```

This *disconnects* the sync-context behaviour, and may improve what you are seeing. You would ideally to add that to *all* of the `await` calls *in the utility method* (`GetPurchaseOrders`).

You may also wish to look for any *missing* `async` operations - for example, the `connection.Open();` could be a `await connection.OpenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);`

Note that the *calling* code **should not** use `ConfigureAwait(false)` - since the binding-list touches the UI, it *needs* the sync-context. So: don't add `ConfigureAwait(false)` to the `await GetPurchaseOrders(...)` call.

---

There is also one other possibility: you say that you are using ODBC and "sage". It is entirely possible that the ODBC/sage API *doesn't support* `await`, and it is being implemented as "sync over async". If this is the case, it gets tricky. You might need to use a *thread* instead of `async`/`await` in that case - perhaps via `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`. There are ways to invoke `async` code on worker threads, but if the "async" code is actually "sync code that pretends to be async", there's not really any point, and you might as well do it "the old way". This usually means:

- start a worker (`ThreadPool`)
- do some work on the worker (your existing code, but perhaps using the non-async implementation)
- at the end of the worker, use `Control.Invoke` to push the work back to the UI thread for the final "update the UI" step

Comment: Since the await captures sync-context, in this case UI, would there be any difference when the calling side uses `await Task.Run(Rest of the code here)` rather than adding `ConfigureAwait(false)` to every async operation in the library?

Comment: @EmrahSüngü it "rest of the code here" includes `await`, then there's a good chance that without the `ConfigureAwait(false)`, it'll just come *straight back* to the UI at the first non-synchronous `await`